# C++11 lambda function won't accept class method

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am probably doing something wrong. Can someone please explain to me what exactly?

Somewhere in class SemanticNodeFactory, I have:

```
    std::pair<C_ptr,R_ptr> Find( Token token  )
    {
      C_ptr concept = nullptr;
      R_ptr relation = nullptr;

      //concept = concept_map->Find( token ); <- This works
      //relation = relation_map->Find( token ); <- And this too

      std::thread t1 ( [&concept,this] ( Token token ) { concept = concept_map->Find( token ); } );
      std::thread t2 ( [&relation,this] ( Token token ) { relation = relation_map->Find( token ); } );
```

The actual methods being called belong to:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Relation> R_ptr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Concept>  C_ptr;

std::shared_ptr<SemanticGraph<Relation>> relation_map;
std::shared_ptr<SemanticGraph<Concept>>  concept_map;
```

However, the compiler complains that:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(SemanticNodeFactory::Find(Token)::<lambda(Token)>) ()’
note: candidate is:
note: SemanticNodeFactory::Find(Token)::<lambda(Token)>
```

However, the actual methods I'm trying to call, are in fact:

```
SemanticGraph<Relation>::Find(Token)
SemanticGraph<Concept>::Find(Token)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm capturing this, the local variables by reference, and yet it seems to complain about the actual method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give `std::thread` a function object taking one parameter - but you don't give it any argument to pass for this parameter. You should either do

```
thread t1([...] () {...});
```

and have `token` be captured, or do

```
thread t1([...] (Token) {...}, token);
```

and pass it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the lambda function! Instead, `std::thread` expects a function taking as many parameters as you choose to pass in addition to the function. Since you lambda functions take on parameter (a `Token`) you'll need to pass that argument, too, e.g.:

```
std::thread t1 ( [&concept,this] ( Token token ) { concept = concept_map->Find( token ); },
                 token );
std::thread t2 ( [&relation,this, token] () { relation = relation_map->Find( token ); } );
```

For the first example the `token` to be passe to the invoked function is passed as a second argument to the constructor of `std::thread`. For the second example the parameter `token` to the function `Find()` is explicitly used in the capture clause.

Note, that a `std::thread` which goes out of scope without calling either `join()` or `detect()` will result in the program being `std::terminate()`d. Thus, make sure you call either of these functions. The safest method guarding against exceptions is to encapsulate the `std::thread` object with a suitable class whose destructor uses the appropriate operation (i.e., `join()`; using `detach()` seems to be an invitation for disaster).